# Why a big part of HDFS is unused and unavailable?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, amazon-emr

In EMR I've had issues where some nodes reach 90% usage in the partition dedicated to HDFS and failed.

To alleviate the problem I've been "freeing up" space by removing spark logs, old checkpoint folders and other logs. However after a while I noticed that the space I was freeing up was not available. To the point where there is a big discrepancy in the output of `hdfs dfs -df -h`, as seen below:
[image]
There are 240GB missing, around 46%.

I first noticed this discrepancy while reading the output of `hdfs dfsadmin -report`. In which something similar can be observed for individual nodes.
[image]

How can I make available the free space? Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

**Why is this happening?**

The missing space in HDFS is explained by space used in `/mnt` in each EMR node outside the `/mnt/hdfs` folder.

So the total space reported by `hdfs dfs -df` corresponds to all the disk space assigned to `/mnt` while the available space is all the space available in `/mnt`. If there is a lot space used within `/mnt` but outside `/mnt/hdfs` the number reported by `hdfs dfs -df` will make little sense.

Here's a visual representation of how the usage of `/mnt` could look like:
[image]

**How can I make available the free space?**

It turned out that yarn container logs where using too much space. These logs are located at `/mnt/var/log/hadoop-yarn/containers/`. I removed any large stderr logs and restarted the corresponding spark application. After that the disk space became available for HDFS.